# Why can’t you use the binary search on the following array?

Tags: c++

Why can't you use the binary search on this array?
int A[10] = {4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 1, -1, 17};

Comment: Because it's not sorted?

Comment: You need to sort it first

Comment: You can use binary search, just not with `operator<`. All arrays with unique values are sorted by at least one comparison operator. I'll leave it as another exercise to find one viable comparison function for these particular 9 values.

Answer (score 3):

In computer science, binary search, also known as half-interval search, logarithmic search, or binary chop, is a search algorithm that finds the position of a target value within a **sorted array**.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)
The Array you use is not sorted and thus Binary Search does not work on it.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to sort it using any of the sorting mechanism

Answer (score 1):

To do binary search firstly you have to sort the array.

You can find the documentation and example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search)

Here is another example:

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::binary_search, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main() {
    int A[10] = {4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 1, -1, 17};
    std::vector<int> v(std::begin(A), std::end(A));
    std::sort (v.begin(), v.end());
    int n = 2;
    // now you can use binary search
    bool foundN = std::binary_search (v.begin(), v.end(), n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Binary search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) requires a sorted collection of elements. For example, if using C++11 or newer, you can easily sort it:

```
std::sort(std::begin(A), std::end(A)); // requires #include <algorithm>
```